# Juice UI Slider Doesnt Work With JQuery UI 1.10.3

Tags: jquery-ui, visual-studio-2012, juice-ui

As far as I can tell Juice UI Slider doesn't work currently with JQuery UI 1.10.3.

I do the following:

Create new project in Visual Studio. 
Update all packages using Nuget (this takes JQuery UI to 1.10.3);
Add Juice UI using Nuget.

Create page with just the following html in the Main Placeholder:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update0">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="sliderHolder">
            <juice:slider ID="slider1" runat="server" CssClass="hSlider" Max="100" Min="50" OnValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"/>
        </div>    
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb0" Text="Current:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbValue"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the following in code behind:
        protected void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbValue.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();
        }

The slider keeps going back to initial value after you drag it and the Label is not updated.

Running the same with JQuery UI 1.9.2 the slider drags, stays at its value and updates the label.

Can somebody let me know if there are fixes or if its a known bug?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also experience the same situation. Seems Juice UI is not compatible with JQuery UI 1.10.3.

Maybe you can try [Brew](http://shellscape.org/brew/), the cousin of Juice UI.

Comment: I haven't tried Brew but looking again at the Juice documentation it does say (at the time of writing) they have only gone to JQuery UI 1.9.2. Therefore when using Visual Studio be careful not to upgrade JQueryUI past that release. Juice itself will upgrade JQueryUI to 1.9.2 if there is a previous level installed in the project.